# How to neglect some part of an expression

Tags: expression-manipulation

I have an expression of the form $a\,x^3 + b\,x^2 + c\,x$ in my answer. I want to avoid those terms in my answer of order 1, but want to keep those of order > 1 in $x$. Can you suggest how to do in *Mathematica* 8?

Comment: Can we see the actual  _Mathematica_ expression from which you want to delete the terms of order < 2? Post the code by editing your question, not by making a comment.

Answer (score 6):

You don't say explicitly how you want to handle terms of order zero. Assuming that these are also to be discarded

```
expr = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d;

minOrder = 2;
coefList = CoefficientList[expr, x];
lenCoefList = Length[coefList];

Expand[(Expand[x*expr] /. ((x^n_ /; n > minOrder) -> $t^n) /. {x -> 0, $t -> 
      x})/x]

(*  b x^2 + a x^3  *)

Subtract @@ ((Series[expr, {x, 0, # - 1}] // Normal) & /@ {lenCoefList, 
    minOrder})

(*  b x^2 + a x^3  *)

ReplacePart[coefList,
  Thread[Range[minOrder] -> 0]].x^Range[0, lenCoefList - 1]

(*  b x^2 + a x^3  *)

Nest[Integrate[#, x] &, D[expr, {x, minOrder}], minOrder]

(*  b x^2 + a x^3  *)
```

EDIT:

To include the constant term, add `Coefficient[expr, x, 0]` to any other solution. This will work whether this coefficient is symbolic, numeric, or any combination.

Comment: I like the differentiate-integrate one.

Comment: I want to neglect only "cx" term...other constants in x are remain as it is...

Answer (score 1):

```
Normal@Series[your expression,{x,0,1}]
```

Comment: No no dear, I want to neglect that part not to collect them. This can be same as "Collect[%,{x}]"....Have any idea...Or I may be wrong ? what does {x,0,1} represents, one by one please...

Comment: You could use `Series` this way: `Normal@Series[a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d /. x -> 1/x, {x, 0, -2}] /. x -> 1/x`

Comment: Hi Yohbs,Thank you somuch